# Python: Merge two lists to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following lists in Python:

```
students = ["Anderson", "Peter", "Anderson", "Bastian"]
courses = ["Biology", "History", "Maths", "History"]
```

I have coded a for loop in an attempt to relate these pairs in a dictionary, so that:

```
Anderson-Biology
Peter-History
Anderson-Maths
Bastian-History
```

The for-loop is as follows:

```
test_dict = {}
for i in range (0, len(students)):
    test_dict[students[i]] = courses[i]
```

However, when printing out the dictionary, I get:

```
{'Bastian': 'History', 'Anderson': 'Maths', 'Peter': 'History'}
```

What has happened to 'Anderson': 'Biology, and is there a way I can solve this?

Comment: A dictionary cannot have duplicate keys , what were you expecting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python dictionaries doesn't accepts duplicate keys and in your code it just preserve the last `'Anderson'`.

Instead you can use `dict.setdefault` method to put the duplicated values in a list :

```
>>> d={}
>>> for i,j in zip(students,courses):
...   d.setdefault(i,[]).append(j)
... 
>>> d
{'Peter': ['History'], 'Anderson': ['Biology', 'Maths'], 'Bastian': ['History']}
>>>
```

Comment: Great, thank you so much! 
How can I access the list (values of each key). Suppose I want to sort them alphabetically.

Comment: @northerner look up Python dicts.